# How to specify multiple paramater Union types as type hints in Python 3.9

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, python-typing

For example, if my code were to be like this in **Python 3.10**:

```py
from typing import Union

class TupleInvalid(Exception):
    pass

TestValue = Union[int, str, float]
TestListA = tuple[str, TestValue]
TestListB = tuple[str, TestValue, TestValue]

def two_or_three(*tuples: TestListA | TestListB) -> str:

    for x in tuples:
        if isinstance(x[0], str):
            if len(x) == 2:
                return 'two'
            elif len(x) == 3:
                return 'three'
            else:
                raise TupleInvalid('Tuple should be 2 or 3 long')
        else:
            raise TupleInvalid(
                'Tuple should be (<str>, <int | float | str>, \
                <int | float | str> (optional)')


print(two_or_three(("test", 3, 4.5)))
print(two_or_three(("testing", 'hi')))
```

My linter would be able to pick up on the fact the argument `*tuples` should be a tuple consisting of either `tuple[str, TestValue]` or `tuple[str, TestValue, TestValue]`. In Python 3.9 however, it doesn't seem to be able to work. I tried making it an `Union[TestListA, TestListB]` but that just gives a lot of errors. (**TypeError:** Cannot instantiate typing.Union)

Using `or` does not give any errors but my linter doesn't seem to be able to find the possible second type then.

```py
(*tuples: TestListA or TestListB)
```

Comment: Which Python 3.9 are you using?

Comment: @ShreyanAvigyan 3.9.4

Comment: It should not occur. Something is wrong

Comment: 3.9.3 had a issue, so it might be a problem but 3.9.4 doesn't have any

Comment: Now I remember. Wait I'm posting an answer

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.9 doesn't have that feature. It is introduced in Python 3.10.